# WPF: Access ObservableCollection from different UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection

I think my problem is quite simple, but I can't seem to find the solution.
I have an application with multiple possible Views(User Controls).
In HomeView-UserControl I create a ObservableCollection.

HomeView.xaml.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<Food> _foodList = new ObservableCollection<Food>();
 public ObservableCollection<Food> FoodList
    {
        get { return _foodList; }
        set { _foodList = value; }
    }
```

I need to access this ObservableCollection from my Statistics-UserControl(and others too).

I tried lots of different approaches líke Commands, complex DataBinding, creating the ObservableCollection in the MainWindow, etc., but I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Are you following an MVVM pattern? If so, your view shouldn't contain parts of the model (just the views for it), it should be in your view model, which can be shared with multiple views if needed...

Comment: Thank you, this already helped me. But what if I edit certain fields (like the Observable Collection) in the HomeViewModel and want those changes to  persist while I am in my SecondView?

Comment: You should be able to pass state data (model data) between views using the methods you call to change views in the view model. For example you can add parameters on the second view model that take in data from the first view, and pass in the collection. Not sure if thats clear or not...

Comment: Thank you!
I can't pass parameters when changing my current view, because I change it in the MainWindow?

Comment: Anyways, you solved my problem and I'd like to set your comment as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you following an MVVM pattern? If so, your view shouldn't contain parts of the model (just the views for it), it should be in your view model, which can be shared with multiple views if needed...

The solution was to have multiple views share the same data dontext.

Credits go to Ron Beyer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different views of the same data, then you should use a `CollectionViewSource`.

For instance, assume you have two `DataGrid`s `dg1`, `dg2`, and an `ObservableCollection` `oc` ... you can write ...

```
cvs1 = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs1 .Source = oc;
cvs1.View.Filter = Filter1;
dg1.ItemsSource = cvs1.View;

cvs2 = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs2 .Source = oc;
cvs2.View.Filter = Filter2;
dg2.ItemsSource = cvs2.View;
```

In this case, `Filter1` and `Filter2` are functions that return `true` when an object maches the filter criteria ... Eg

```
private bool Filter1(object o)
{
     \\return true if o has correct properties
}
```